# Domain/URL Masking

Tags: php, url, masking

I have a website that passes some GET variables to different pages in PHP. My issue is that now I have a url with variables i.e. index.php?category=categoryname and that's not very memorable.

Is there any way I can change the URL to something like /categoryname instead without duplicating the page and storing in folders? But also allow users to type in /categoryname and be redirected to the correct page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.htaccess Apache mod_rewrite, almost every professional dynamic website uses this method (like stackoverflow).

The method is fully explained in [this article](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html) far better then I could ever explain it in this answer box.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into writing some apache `Mod_Rewrite` rules in a `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is discussed [here](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/890307-url-use-instead-send-variables):

> this is done by the rewrite module of apache and this handles regular
>   expressions. You have to put a rule
>   like this in your .htaccess file on
>   the root of your website:

RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9]+)$
/index.php?category=$1

> ^ means the start of the url after
>   www.example.com/ $ means the end of
>   the page.

www.example.com/cat/123

> will be converted by the server to:

www.example.com/index.php?category=123

> In PHP you use the normal $_GET['id']
>   variable. The rewrite module must be
>   enabled by apache... This is mostly
>   used to make the url format
>   independent of the serverside
>   scripting language so the .php in the
>   url is not logical. Thats why i
>   changed it to product/ . The .htaccess
>   starts with
>
> RewriteEngine On Options
>   +FollowSymLinks RewriteBase / Here all the rewrite rules.. ...